# Using Apache-Spark, reduce or fold an RDD depending on a condition

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, reduce, fold

I'm working with Apache Spark and Scala. I have an RDD of String,Int

```scala
val counts =words.map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey((a,b) => (a + b))
```

Now I reduced the RDD by Key, but I'd like to add another feature to reduce also the words that are similar.

I though to use Levenshtein distance, Euclidean distance or cosine distance.

So, how can I apply one of this functions to reduce my RDD?

Example:

```scala
RDD ->  (forks,12), (fork,4), (chair,15) , (table,1), (tables,11)
```

Admitting that the similarity algorithm works, how can I obtain a reduced RDD like:

```scala
RDD -> (fork,16), (table,12), (chair,15)
```

I tried something like:

```scala
counts.foldLeft(){(x,y) => 
  if(x._1.euclideanDistance(y._1) > 0.9) 
    (x,x._2+y._2) 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

What you are trying will not work.

If you only have a `distance(a, b)` function, it is really inefficient and complicated to solve the problem. You would need to use `RDD.cartesian` to generate all the possible `(word1, word2)` pairs. Then filter out those with too great a distance. Now you have the similar word pairs. Let's say they are `(fox, fix)`, `(fix, six)`, and their reversals. You then want to sum up the counts for `fox`, `fix`, and `six`. For this you need to find the *connected components* in the graph defined by the similar word pairs. Once you have the component ID for each word, you sum the counts by the component IDs.

I think the solution rather is to write a function that can turn a word into its "canonical" form. It would turn `forks`, `forking`, and `forked` into `fork`. Then you can just apply this and `reduceByKey` again.

It will be fastest to do this step without Spark. Once you have calculated `counts` with Spark, you have a tiny data set — one integer for each distinct word. It's easiest to `collect` it and then `map` and `groupBy` `counts` locally.

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel's reply is probably the proper way to go to solve the overall problem.

Regarding the specific q. when you do an `if` in the fold you need also to supply the `else` in your case that would be preserving x with it's current count